# Динамическое создание таблицы с кнопками

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Требуется создать таблицу с кнопками, которая будет генерироваться автоматически на основе данных в базе данных в момент выполнения программы.
И ещё желательно какие-то фильтры и сортировки

**Пример таблицы**

```
id | name| firstame | action
1  |  qqq|          |  delete, update,up
2  |  www|          |  delete, update,up
```

кнопки, как я понимаю, должны содержать уникальные id, чтобы понять какую запись нужно удалить.

В общем пока слабо понимаю как это можно реализовать на WinForms. Про DataGrid слушал, но ещё больше запутался.

База данных sqlite.

Comment: Про динамическое создание формы (таблицы, кнопки) яснее можете написать? Какие кнопки и какие действия должны совершаться по клику на них? Зачем вам EntityFramework если у вас всего одна таблица с заранее известной структурой? EntityFramework нужен разработчикам если модель хранения и сами сущности бизнес модели изменяются в процессе разработки проекта. Если же модель хранения элементарна (одна таблица), то лучше обойтись либо прямой работой через ADO.Net либо каким-то легким ORM типа dapper. Посмотрите [видеоурок](https://youtu.be/ayp3tHEkRc0) и просто попробуйте повторить.

Comment: Таблиц в базе данных  должно быть 3 . Клиенты, Договора, График оплаты.
По клику на кнопку, например, должна удалиться запись из  базы данных.
Или открыться окно с формой, в которой можно изменить эту запись.

Comment: Или открыться окно с формой, в которой можно изменить эту запись в базе данных.
Понимаю, как это сделать на html-js-php, но не понимаю, как это сделать на C#

Comment: Во-первых, не задавайте два разных вопроса в одной теме. Удалите отсюда вопрос про ошибку сохранения и создайте новую тему про это. Во-вторых, в заголовке у вас _создание формы_, в теле вопроса _создать таблицу_. Так что нужно-то?

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример приложения.

В примере данные в список заносятся вручную. Вы должны сделать загрузку из БД. Как именно - решать вам. Это может быть сырой ADO.NET (вручную написанные sql-запросы с использованием `SqlDataReader`), или `SqlDataAdapter` + `DataTable`, или ORM типа EntityFramework.

Так как используется привязка данных (data binding) то применяем `BindingList` - при этом будут работать события добавления/удаления элементов в коллекции.

После того, как данные загружены и привязаны к датагриду, создаём и помещаем в него колонки типа `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. Для обработки нажатий на них используется обработчик события `CellContentClick`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButtonColumn;
        DataGridViewButtonColumn updateButtonColumn;
        BindingList<Person> persons;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Width = 600;
            dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };

            // тут подразумевается получение данных из БД
            persons = new BindingList<Person>
            {
                new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
                new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Vasya", LastName = "Pupkin" },
                new Person { Id = 3, FirstName = "Alice", LastName = "Drake" }
            };

            dataGridView.DataSource = persons;

            deleteButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
            {
                HeaderText = "Delete Action",
                Name = "DeleteButton",
                Text = "Delete",
                UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
            };
            updateButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
            {
                HeaderText = "Update Action",
                Name = "UpdateButton",
                Text = "Update",
                UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
            };

            dataGridView.Columns.Add(deleteButtonColumn);
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(updateButtonColumn);

            dataGridView.CellContentClick += DataGridView_CellContentClick;
        }

        private void DataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0) // исключаем хедер
            {
                var buttonColumn = dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonColumn;

                if (buttonColumn == deleteButtonColumn)
                {
                    if (persons.Any())
                    {
                        var person = persons[e.RowIndex];
                        // Тут удаляем объект из БД
                        // Айдишник известен: person.Id - используйте его в sql-запросе

                        //if (/*удаление из БД прошло успешно*/)
                        {
                            // Удаляем объект из коллекции
                            // Благодаря привязке данных, удалится строка из датагрида
                            persons.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (buttonColumn == updateButtonColumn)
                {
                    // тут ваши действия по обновлению
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```